# Change graph visualization with networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I need a clarification with the plot. Using the code below I can see my graph:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))


position = nx.spring_layout(DG, seed=7)

# Add nodes
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(DG, position, node_size=250, node_color='blue')
nx.draw_networkx_labels(DG, position, font_size=10, font_family="sans-serif")

# Add edges
nx.draw_networkx_edges(DG, position, width=3, edge_color='orange', arrowstyle='->', arrowsize=25)
edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'orig-id')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(
    G,
    pos=position,
    edge_labels=edge_labels,
    font_size=15,

)

plt.show()
```

[image]

But I would like to see a circular graph as explaned [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/tutorial.html). So, I've changed my code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

nx.draw_circular(DG)

position = nx.spring_layout(DG, seed=7)

# Add nodes
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(DG, position, node_size=250, node_color='blue')
nx.draw_networkx_labels(DG, position, font_size=10, font_family="sans-serif")

# Add edges
nx.draw_networkx_edges(DG, position, width=3, edge_color='orange', arrowstyle='->', arrowsize=25)
edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'orig-id')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(
    G,
    pos=position,
    edge_labels=edge_labels,
    font_size=15,

)

plt.show()
```

And the result is this
[image]

It is not clear for me how I can plot the graph with orange edges like the graph with black edges.

Comment: The problem comes from drawing your network twice with different layouts (`nx.circular_layout` and `nx.spring_layout`). Try removing the `nx.draw_circular(DG)` line and change `position = nx.spring_layout(DG, seed=7)` to `position = nx.circular_layout(DG)`

Comment: Add the answer so I can vote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are drawing the network twice, because [`nx.draw_circular()`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_circular.html) draws the entire network as a side effect. (That function can take a lot of arguments to control how edges, vertices, etc, are drawn, but you already have that code laid out so it's probably not the best approach.)

Instead, you should make a circular *position* dictionary using [`nx.circular_layout(G)`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.circular_layout.html), then use that in the other drawing code. For example:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

# Compute positions.
position = nx.circular_layout(DG, seed=7)

# Add nodes and labels.
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(DG, position, node_size=250, node_color='blue')
nx.draw_networkx_labels(DG, position, font_size=10, font_family="sans-serif")

# Add edges and labels.
nx.draw_networkx_edges(DG, position, width=3, edge_color='orange', arrowstyle='->', arrowsize=25)
edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'orig-id')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,
                             pos=position,
                             edge_labels=edge_labels,
                             font_size=15,
                             )
```